# Liferay 7.x with Tomcat 8 in Eclipse Neon 2 is taking too much time to start

Tags: liferay, tomcat8, liferay-7

I am running Liferay 7 modules using Liferay 7.x with Tomcat 8 configuration in Eclipse Neon 2 IDE. It is taking too much time to start the application. I tried stopping and starting the server several times but no use. Taking min half an hour.

One possibly relevant entry in the logs is:

> 13:29:43,987 INFO [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PluginPackageUtil:1267] Reloading repositories

Comment: Analyze the logs and tell us which particular step takes too much time. Currently, your question doesn't contain any useful diagnostic information.

Comment: 13:29:43,987 INFO  [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-1][PluginPackageUtil:1267] Reloading repositories. This is the one which takes time I think. And can you please tell me what kind of diagnostic information you want to know